# Could not find method dependencyResolutionManagement() for arguments [build_ckqar66poaozqtyzw4dyn6sx4$_run_closure3@a921a13] on project app

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I have a trouble in my build.gradle file because there is a method called dependencyResolutionManagement() but I don't know how to solve it.
The error says that there are not method.
This is the message:
Also I have an error that says 'Cannot Resolve symbol 'RepositoriesMode' on my build gradle.
I think I was modifying my build.gradle to add some dependence but I did something wrong. These are the message and my build.gradle file

```
    build.gradle

    1 error

    Could not find method dependencyResolutionManagement() for arguments [build_ckqar66poaozqtyzw4dyn6sx4$_run_closure3@a921a13] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project

    This is my build.gradle file

    Cannot resolve symbol 'RepositoriesMode'

    import org.gradle.api.initialization.resolve.RepositoriesMode

    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
     }

    android {
        compileSdk 31
        buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
           applicationId 'com.example.myapp'
          minSdk 21
           targetSdk 30
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

            testInstrumentationRunner                     "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
         }
        allprojects {
           repositories {
               google()
               mavenCentral()
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
             release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-       a.ndroid-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
        }
        compileOptions {
             sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
             targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
         }
         buildFeatures {
             viewBinding true
         }
     }

     dependencies {
         implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.5.0'
         implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
         implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
         implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
         implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging'
         implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
         implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
         implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.5.0'
         testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
          androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    }

    dependencyResolutionManagement {
                           repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
                 repositories {
                      google()
                      mavenCentral()
                      jcenter()
             maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
         }
     }
              rootProject.name = "appname"
              include ':app'
```

I tried Invalidate- Restart Caché but it didn't work. I think I was modifying the build.gradle code and I made something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Remove from your build.gradle file

   ```
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }
   ```
2. Add to your settings.gradle the next code section:

   ```
   dependencyResolutionManagement {
       repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
       repositories {
           google()
           mavenCentral()
           maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
           jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
       }
   }
   ```
3. Try to sync again your project

This worked for me!!